# Token expiry issue in dropbox

Tags: php, laravel, api, dropbox

I tried this code for getting access token by it's giving me this error.

```
curl https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token \
    -d grant_type=refresh_token \
    -d refresh_token=<REFRESH_TOKEN> \
    -u <APP_KEY>:<APP_SECRET>
```

getting this error

```
Client error: `POST https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error_description": "refresh token is malformed", "error": "invalid_grant"}
```

code is expiring after some time so i have to put token manually from Dropbox site

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

TOKEN IS SOMTHING LIKE THIS

```
sl.A5gzYO9XTUXHhxYB0qLnP-Ycp9nDP4w1Jwr0g5p-DdsfSD,MFN4KBk6i1DCgeoN13zd2-BG6XwO_TQO95_N9e84ZD_C7uSNcp--GHrDmLqIfFVRsvNPRNFqL9HiVeBhm_C
```

Comment: How do you use refresh token?

Comment: i need token for creating and getting folders from dropbox

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't appear to match the error message to begin with. You are making a request to exchange a `code` parameter for an access token here - whereas an actual token refresh request would use `grant_type=refresh_token`, and send a `refresh_token` _to_ refresh.

Comment: for REFRESH_TOKEN which token i have to pass? any hint ? @CBroe

Comment: I recommend reading [the OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) to get an understanding of how this flow works.